# Testing functions in class which expects string in constructor using Mockito

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

I have the following class and want to write unit test for it. Below is the class for full reference. `X` is POJO

```
public class StatusTable {
    private P tableData;
    private Q tableDefinition;

    public StatusTable(final List<X> xList,
        final A a,
        final B b)
        throws URISyntaxException {
        setTableDefinition(a, b);
        setTableData(xList, b, a);
    }


    private void setTableDefinition(final A a,
        final B b) {
        //some code
    }

    public void setTableData(final List<X> xList,
            final B b, final A a)
        throws URISyntaxException {
        for (X sfm : xList) {
            //some code
        }
    }
}
```

Being new to unit testing, I have very minimal idea of how to test but here is a thought. Please correct me wherever incorrect.

```
public class StatusTableTest {

private StatusTable statusTable;
@Mock
private A mockA;
@Mock
private B mockB;
@Mock
private X mockX;

    public void setUp() {
        stub(mockX.getSomeValue()).toReturn(?);   //want to return any string
        stub(mockX.getSomeAnotherValue()).toReturn(?);   //want to return any integer
        //Similarly mock other functions retuning 
        this.statusTable = new StatusTable(xList, mockA, mockB,);
    }

    public void setTableDefinitionTest() {
        //test the code
    }
}
```

I have a few doubts:

a) Am I doing it correctly? Should the X be mocked?

b) Is there anyString() kind of functionality in Mockito or should I use something else?

Answer (score 0):

a) It is hard to tell without actual code. You can mock individual X values or whole List of X.

b) Your end result is based on expected values, so you should not return anyString(), but some specific String. So you can verify that your code behaves correctly for this particular String. I.e. assert that table contains single cell with "abc" text if passed list with one X returning "abc".

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you want to mock.

You can mock any call to your class and return any value or spy on an existing class and overload a call with your mocked call.

For instance

```
mockedX = Mockito.mock(X.class);

Mockito.when(mockedX.someFunction("1")).thenReturn(someAnswer);
```

or:

```
X x = new X();
spiedX = Mockito.spy(x);

Mockito.answer(some answer).when(spiedX).someFunction("1");
```

Remember ... the mocked class will return what you are mocking.

If you create a mock like this:

```
Mockito.when(mockedX.someFunction(Mockito.anyString())).thenReturn("A");
```

then on every call someFunction() will return "A".